# saving database on phpMyAdmin - mySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created a database with two tables on my phpMyAdmin account, and I'm using 000webhost for a web hosting. Once I logged out of my account, and re logged in, everything was deleted. Does anyone know how I can save the database I have re added? thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a database would persist across login sessions. The only possible exception would be if you log in as different users (which could be different usernames or if you use fine-grained IP-based access controls, for instance, two different users both with username `natasha`, one host `192.0.2.1` and another with host `192.0.2.50`). If those users don't have full access, they might not be able to see the database owned by the other user.

Other than that, I can't think of any reason your data wouldn't persist and suggest you contact your hosting provider's support for further assistance.